# Is it possible to launch different url based on a specific condition in gauge and taiko using javascript

Tags: javascript, gauge, taiko

In the current gauge/taiko project, the application url and login credentials is configured based on different test environments inside user.properties file

Now, I have 2 different urls for the same environment. if I have to launch 2nd url and perform the same test steps. If yes, how can this be done? Is this possible without changing the existing test steps and manipulate only the login part? Please clarify